# How to create a Custom error function with data

Tags: javascript

I want to make custom error function with a data object and export it. Right now my function looks like this:

```
function dataError(message, data) {
    this.name = 'dataError';
    this.message = message;
    this.data = data || {};


}
dataError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
dataError.prototype.constructor = dataError;

module.exports = { dataError };
```

But the problem is that when I'm extending it and making it's instance:

```
const errors = require('./Errors');
let fieldsErrors = {prop: "value"};

let err = new errors.dataError("Validation error", fieldsErrors);
console.log(err);
```

There is nothing inside my data object. What's wrong with my code and how do I make it work?

Comment: `module.exports = { dataError : dataError };`

Comment: I'm partly using es6, so it's a valid part.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. `err.data` is `{prop: "value"}` for me.

Comment: How and in which version of node do you test your code? Works for me `v8.1.2`

Comment: I'm working on node v7.10.1

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this sort of construct by going full ES6:

```
class DataError extends Error {
  constructor (message, data = {}) {
    super(message)

    this.data = data
  }

  get name () {
    return this.constructor.name
  }
}

module.exports = { DataError }
```

Demo:

```js
class DataError extends Error {
  constructor (message, data = {}) {
    super(message)

    this.data = data
  }
  
  get name () {
    return this.constructor.name
  }
}

let dataErr = new DataError('Validation error', { prop: 'value' })

console.log(dataErr.name)
console.log(dataErr.message)
console.log(dataErr.data)
```